# Testing CommonJS modules that use browserify aliases and shims

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, commonjs, browserify

Browserify allows creating aliases and shimming modules that are not directly CommonJS compatible. Since I'd like to run my tests in node CLI, can I somehow handle those aliases and shimmed modules in node?

For example, let's say I'm aliasing `./my-super-module` to `supermodule` and shimming and aliasing some jquery plugin `./vendor/jquery.plugin.js` -> `./shims/jquery.plugin.shim.js` to `jquery.plugin`.

As a result, I can do this in my module:

```
var supermodule = require('supermodule');
require('jquery.plugin');

// do something useful...
module.exports = function(input) {
  supermodule.process(output)
}
```

Are there any practices how I could test this module in node.js/cli so that the dependencies are resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) if you plan to test this module directly in node using any cli runner.

using mocha will be something like this

```
describe('test', function () {
  var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
  it('should execute some test', function () {
     var myModule = proxyquire('./my-module', {
         // define your mocks to be used inside the modules
        'supermodule' : require('./mock-supermodule'),
        'jquery.plugin': require('./jquery-plugin-mock.js')
     });
  });
});
```

If you want to test this is a real browser, you might not need to mock your aliases modules, you can use `browserify` to run your tests in `karma` directly.

If you need to mock modules in that scenario you can use [proxyquireify](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquireify), which will allow you to do the same but with `browserify`.

there is also [browsyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browsyquire) which is a fork of `proxyquireify` that I made with some extra features and a [bug fix](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquireify/pull/41).