# Is there a way to use a non CommonJS module in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, commonjs, browserify-shim

Let's say someone didn't publish their module in npm and even if they did let's say they didn't have it as commonjs module. Would there be a way to still use that plugin or module inside node? I'm aware that we can use node code in browsers using browserify but I was just wondering if there's a way to do the other way around.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597469/testing-commonjs-modules-that-use-browserify-aliases-and-shims) question seems like the most closest that I'm looking into but there's no response yet.

What my end goal really is to be able to use libraries that are not specifically CJS module in node and still be able to test my code in node/cli.

Comment: You can use code that is not in the commonjs format, but you'd have to write your own loader for it or find a loader module that supports what you have.

Comment: Loader in this context would be something like require in node right? I thought it had to do more with exposing the global variable that the plugin is using rather than loader. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: A loader (like what `require()` does) needs to load code from disk into memory and then do whatever needs to be done (given the format the code is in) to execute it and somehow expose the symbols it intends to be public.

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense. So there isn't a generic loader for all the modules that aren't CJS. Each module has to have their own specific loader to tell what to expose. Thanks. I was under impression that browserify-shim did that but looks like it's just exposes modules from browserified bundle to browsers.